# Referencing json from a different file

Tags: swagger-ui

Maybe I'm not quite understanding swagger quite yet (just did a tutorial). But I am trying to create documentation for an API we are building. Everything points to swagger, so decided to try that. Got it working pretty well. The issue I am having though is moving a schema from the swagger.json file to a seperate file to keep things clean.

The way the documentation has it, you give it a `type` and then `$ref` which I did. I then linked it to a file within a folder (of another folder) within the current directory.

```
{
...
"schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
             ...
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Not exactly this but this gives a good idea of `what I had working`. If I have this in the same file, this works as I want it to. The issue I am having now is trying to move the `properties` to another file, as documented in the swagger [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)  (maybe this is where I am misunderstanding).

So, I then take away the `properties` object, and replace it with:

```
"schema": {
     "type": "object",
     "$ref": "./components/schemas/staticData"
}
```

Here's what the external file looks like:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "data": {
          ...
        }
     }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

`Resolver error at paths./*/*.get.responses.200.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: undefined undefined` (I obfuscated the path since it's irrelevant and I don't want our paths to be on a public website).

What I am looking for is how the external file needs to be structured so I can put these schemas in a different file and not clog up the root swagger.json file.

*EDIT* This is the folder structure

```
 public
  components
     schemas
       staticData.json
  swagger.json
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the name of the external file and where is it located related to the main file?

Comment: ill put it in my question wont let me do multi line

Comment: @Helen updated question.